# Automatically import Typescript namespace from namespace/type only NPM module in mono-repo

Tags: typescript, npm, serverless-framework

I have a number of private repositories that use the same Typescript types repeatedly so instead of copying them from one project to another, I have created a private NPM package that houses all of these shared types under a Typescript namespace. Each project installs that NPM package if it uses the shared types.

**index.d.ts**

```
export * as v1_6 from './types/version1_6';

export as namespace SharedNamespace;
```

One of the projects that use these types is a Serverless mono-repo that has this project structure:

```
package.json
tsconfig.json
|_ lib
|_ services
    |_ service1
    |_ service2
    |_ service3
    |_ service4
    |_ serviceX
```

Where the tsconfig.json is in the parent directory and then there are several serverless projects in a `services` sub-directory, where only `service1` has the private NPM types installed.

When I try to use the namespace inside of the `service1` project, I get an error:

```
Cannot find namespace 'SharedNamespace'.
```

Which I assume I am getting for two reasons:

1. Our types are not in the default `./node_modules/@types` location.
2. Since our NPM module is only Typescript namespaces we never `import` it anywhere in our project

**My question is, what is the best way to have it included in our global type scope?**

My first attempt was to extend the base `tsconfig.json` file with a custom one inside of the `service1` directory:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": [
      "../../node_modules/@types",
      "./node_modules/@types",
      "./node_modules/@myOrg/privateTypes"
    ]
  },
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json"
}
```

But even after the I get the same error.

However, if I do import the namespace manually where I need it, the error goes away. Ideally, we wouldn't have to import it all the time.

## Update 1

If I use the following `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@myOrg/privateTypes"
    ]
  },
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json"
}
```

I now get the error `Cannot find type definition file for 'types'. The file is in the program because: Entry point for implicit type library 'types'.`

However in the `package.json` of the private NPM module:

```
  "main": "",
  "types": "index.d.ts",
  "typeScriptVersion": "3.9.7",
```

and in the project directory:

[image: Private NPM Module Directory]

So I am not sure why it cannot find that file?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the exact same problem today. So OK, that's more than a year later and I hope you've found a suitable answer since you wrote this question.

Give a try to the `include` option in `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "include": [
    ".",
    "./node_modules/@myOrg/privateTypes/index.d.ts"
  ]
}
```